# Как распарсить ответ от сервера

Tags: java, android, json

Один нехороший человек написал мне веб-сервис на PHP, который выдает номера телефонов. Почему нехороший - потому что отправляет он мне в таком виде:

```
[77012260000,77012260001,77012260002,77012260003,77012260004,77012260005,77012260006,77012260007].
```

Как мне ее закинуть в `List` или массив (распасить)?

Cижу и не могу понять, вроде JSON и вроде нет. Поймать я его не могу чтоб заставить переписать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Без точки в конце строки это совершенно [валидный](http://www.json.org/json-ru.html) JSON.

Снаружи - массив (array), элементы массива (value) - числа (number).

Пример парсинга Jackson-ом:

```
String json = "[77012260000,77012260001,77012260002,77012260003,77012260004,77012260005,77012260006,77012260007]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List list = mapper.readValue(json, List.class);
System.out.println(list);  // [77012260000, 77012260001, 77012260002, 77012260003, 77012260004, 77012260005, 77012260006, 77012260007]
```

Answer (score 3):

Проблемы то нет:

1. Убираем лишнее

   ```
   String s = "[77012260000,77012260001,77012260002,77012260003,77012260004,77012260005,77012260006,77012260007].";
   s = s.subString(1, s.indexOf("]"));
   ```
2. Разбиваем на массив по запятой:

   ```
   String[] array = s.split(",");
   ```

Answer (score 3):

я бы сделал через [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Long>>() {}.getType();
List<Long> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```